# No Attribute : 'audit' found while using smtplib to send emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, attributeerror, smtplib

I was trying to **send emails** through `smtplib`, but i always get an **Attribute error**. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python\smtplib.py", line 195, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python\smtplib.py", line 275, in connect
    sys.audit("smtplib.connect", self, host, port)
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'audit'
```

> I know i am getting error because of this line in my code:
>
> ```
> # Step 7 - Create the server connection               
> server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
> ```

**Here is my code:**

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

# Step 2 - Create message object instance
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# Step 3 - Create message body
message = "Test from Python via AuthSMTP"

# Step 4 - Declare SMTP credentials
password = "password"
username = "andrew.whiteman77@gmail.com"

# Step 5 - Declare message elements
msg['From'] = "your.name@your-domain-name.com"
msg['To'] = "your.name@your-domain-name.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Test from Python via AuthSMTP"

# Step 6 - Add the message body to the object instance
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

# Step 7 - Create the server connection                      # here is the line
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)                 # where i am getting error!!!

# Step 8 - Switch the connection over to TLS encryption 
server.starttls()

# Step 9 - Authenticate with the server
server.login(username, password)

# Step 10 - Send the message
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

# Step 11 - Disconnect
server.quit()

# Step 12 -
print("Successfully sent email message to %s:") % (msg['To'])
```

When i debug my file, it shows that:
[image: Attribute error in module itself]

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Could you share smtplib version, which you are using for that run?

Comment: I don't exactly know. When i try to install smtplib using pip then it was not there, so i just copied it's source code and pasted in a new file i.e smtplib.py. Any help will be appreciated, and i guess it's the latest one.

Comment: Well, this is the link to it's official site's source code : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/smtplib.py

Comment: I don't get any error with Pythın 3.7.3 and the latest version of smtplib. I even get an security warning from Gmail.

Comment: So what should i do know?

Comment: Your code has no error, You can try to re-install/upgrade your Python distribution.

Comment: Please review my question again! When i debug my file it shows smtplib has no attribute audit. That means the module itself has errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sys.audit()** added after **Python 3.8.0**, to call this method you should use Python +3.8 [Docs Audit Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html)

> This table contains all events raised by **sys.audit()** or **PySys_Audit()** calls throughout the CPython runtime and the standard library. T**hese calls were added in 3.8.0 or later**.

In [smtplib Blob CPython 3.7 Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/smtplib.py) you can see that they didn't use sys.audit(). So, your problem is about your Python version.

Comment: Well that really worked for me now after your advice for upgrading python version but was producing an authentication error. To solve it, i must edit my google security settings but is there any way for doing this without changing my settings or security so that google will provide me authentication??

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the python to 3.8 to fix this issue.

```py
python3 -V
sudo apt-get install python3.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Select either `2` or the serial number pointing to v3.8 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can confirm your version with

```py
python3 -V
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the third line, installing `python3.6.1`? Is that necessary or recommended e.g. as a fallback for legacy support?